# Validate Map<String,Object> object matches json schema

Tags: java, jackson, jsonschema

I have a json schema, for example:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "ignoreUnknown": true,
  "properties": {
    "address" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to check whether an object of type `Map<String,Object>` matches the schema or not.
The schema is received as a String.

How can I achieve this in Java? (Preferably using Jackson)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Maybe it seems like that to you, but I was just asking if someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: You can find a list of implementations here: https://json-schema.org/implementations.html

Answer (score 0):

Although it isn't Jackson-based, you can do that using the [everit-org/json-schema](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema) library as follows:

```java
Map<String, Object> myInstance = ...
SchemaLoader.builder()
    .schemaJson(new JSONObject("{my-schema-json}"))
    .build().load().build().validate(new JSONObject(myInstance));
```

*Disclaimer: I am a developer of this library*

Comment: You need to make it clear if you are a developer of a library that you are recommending. It seems you are, so I added it. Next time, please remember